# Closure: 'Do Tempur-pedic mattresses differ in material? '

Tags: discussion

I know little about mattresses. How can [Do Tempur-pedic mattresses markedly differ in material?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/44332/16959) be revised to be on-topic please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a claim which is:

- specific
- is believed by many people
- or, at the very least, has been seen by many people
- that is objective (not an opinion)
- that you are doubtful about the truth of.

Link to where it is made, and quote the relevant part.

---

The current quotes do not match the title (which is something you seem to have changed to try to resurrect the question) and don't make the claim it makes.

There is nothing to address.

Comment: What if I ask whether Tempur-pedic mattresses have unique advantages compared to other mattresses?

Comment: Can you hit those points? I can't see how. Remember one of the unique advantages of luxury goods is the branding itself - how it makes you feel and how it makes others see you. So, no matter what the brand, the answer will be yes.